# How to update textboxes in a loop without updating them all

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem in updating textboxes, when I update at least one textbox into the database it fills all of the existing textboxes **THAT ARE NULL** in the gridview.

I know it's because of the loop through the datatable but how can I fix that? How can I update just the ones that the user modified? I already tried textchanged but didn't work at all. I already tried getting all the rows in the "dtTmp" and then compare current values with the old values in datatable but didn't work either.

Here's the code:

```
try
{
    DataTable dtTmp = (DataTable)Session["dtTmp"]; 
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvEdit.Rows)
    {
        string Id = gvEdit.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    
        TextBox TbCourseEdit = (row.FindControl("TbCourseEdit") as TextBox);
        for (int i = 0; i < dtTmp.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Id == dtTmp.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString())
            {
                s.ID = Id;
                s.CourseID = int.TryParse(s.CourseNameToID(TbCourseEdit.Text).ToString(), out var CourseID) ? CourseID : (int?)null;
                
                s.ScheduleToMoodleTemplateSave();
                MessageBox1.Message = "Saved";  
            }
        }
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ApplicationLog.Write(ApplicationLog.logType.error, null, "ScheduleMoodleTemplate.SaveBulkEdit()", ex.Message);
}
```

Here's the code to s.SchedulToMoodleTemplateSave()

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
            if (this.ID != null)
            {
                ht.Add("ID", this.ID);
            }
            ht.Add("MoodleTemplateID", this.MoodleTemplateID);
            ht.Add("ScheduleTypeID", this.ScheduleTypeID);
            ht.Add("DeliverTypeID", this.DeliverTypeID);
            ht.Add("CourseID", this.CourseID);
            try
            {
                SqlToolbox.SpExecuteInt(Config.connectionString, "ScheduleMoodleTemplateSave", ht);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
```

Comment: Where's the code where you're updating a textbox? This code appears to just read from a texbox.

Comment: It's this one s.ScheduleToMoodleTemplateSave(); I'll post the code in to this procedure in a second.

Comment: @SethFlowers The code to update the textbox is already on the post. Thank you very much for taking the time to read through it.

Answer (score 0):

To let a user freely tab around in the grid, edit/change things?

Try doing this way:

```
create the datatable.
persist the datatable (say in Viewstate)
send table to grid view
```

Now to save all edits?

```
send grid back to table
execute a update on the table - ONLY changes will update for you!
```

In fact, since each plain jane asp.net control in a gv requires that 'template' field, then I often find that a listview is a better choice.

but, lets go with a gv for this example.

our markup:

```
    <div style="width:40%;margin-top:20px;margin-left:20px">
        <style> .borderhide input {border:none}</style>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" 
            cssclass="table table-hover borderhide">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="First Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" Text = '<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Last Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server" Text = '<%# Eval("LastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="City">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Text = '<%# Eval("City") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Active">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="Active" runat="server" Checked = '<%# Eval("Active") %>'></asp:CheckBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
            <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="btn-primary" OnClick="cmdSave_Click1" />

            <asp:Button ID="cmdAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Row" CssClass="btn-primary" style="margin-left:20px"/>
            <br />
     </div>
```

Ok, code to load the gv is thus this:

```
    private DataTable rstPeople = new DataTable();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadGrid();
        ViewState["MyTable"] = rstPeople;
    }
    else
        rstPeople = (DataTable)ViewState["MyTable"];

    }
    public void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from People", 
                                    new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();

            rstPeople.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());

            GridView1.DataSource = rstPeople;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

note how we have the data table at the class level here. And note how we persit the table into ViewState.

Ok, so the output now looks like this:

[image]

And bonus is that we did hide the text box borders, but when they get focus, they show like this:

[image]

So, now we can tab around - it actually feels almost like Excel.

and the code for the save button is thus this:

```
    protected void cmdSave_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        // pull grid rows back to table.

        foreach (GridViewRow rRow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            int RecordPtr = rRow.RowIndex;

            DataRow OneDataRow;

            OneDataRow = rstPeople.Rows[RecordPtr];
            OneDataRow["FirstName"] = ((TextBox)rRow.FindControl("txtFirst")).Text;
            OneDataRow["LastName"] = ((TextBox)rRow.FindControl("txtLast")).Text;
            OneDataRow["City"] = ((TextBox)rRow.FindControl("txtCity")).Text;
            OneDataRow["Active"] = ((CheckBox)rRow.FindControl("Active")).Checked;
        }

        // now send table back to database with updates

        string strSQL = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, City, Active from People WHERE ID = 0";

        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, 
                                    new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter daupdate = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
            SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuild = new SqlCommandBuilder(daupdate);

            daupdate.Update(rstPeople);
        }
    }
```

So note how we execute ONE update to send the whole shebang back to the database. And the table providers are quite smart - only rows updated are actually sent back to the table - rows without updates/changes don't generate traffic.

And I also tossed in a add row button - it ALSO will be included and "added" as a new row into the database in that "single" update. Again, this makes code rather easy, since no messy adding, or checking to add a row vs one simple update command as per above.

And the add row code? That's easy and looks like this:

```
   protected void cmdAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // add a new row to the grid

        DataRow OneRow = rstPeople.Rows.Add();
        GridView1.DataSource = rstPeople;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer , but I used another approach since this one wasn't working... I decided to use a dropdown list with a search filter instead of a textbox with AutoCompleteExtender and it fixed my problem.